# Scrollbar only on one div and not the whole body

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow

I have a problem, i am making a website for a friend and he wanted a horizontale one page website, 
but i have a problem, i want to create it like this that you can scroll the page vertical if the page is longer then the screen, BUT i want the scrollbar IN the div and not over the whole body content.

I created a image quickly what i mean with the scrollbar. 
and on this moment if had did it over the whole body all the other pages got the same height if one page was longer then the other one.

**Image:**

[image]

**Live example:** http://onepage.ringocontent.com/

The live example is how i described it above about that all the pages get the same height if only one page get a overflow with the height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to your stylesheet should solve the problem:

```
<style> 
    #home, #blog, #info, #contact { 
        overflow-y: scroll; 
        height: 500px; 
    } 
    #page { 
        height: auto; 
    } 
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, sadly it didn't work, i updated the live example with what you said but i still get the body scrollbar.
I want the scrollbar in the <div id="content"></div>
In that div, do i set al the page content that need to scroll.

Comment: Okay please try adding these styles as they're to your stylesheet, this should hopefully resolve your problem:

`<style>
#home, #blog, #info, #contact { overflow-y: scroll; height: 500px; }
#page { height: auto; }
</style>`

Comment: @PindaWorld I've updated my main answer with the new solution and the reference image. Hopefully this is what you require.

Comment: Thankyou Fahad! your answer was kinda right i edited a little bit with your answer and figure how i got it right how i wanted it. You can see the live Example for how it is now! thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for here is the overflow property of an element. Particularly overflow-y.

If you apply

```
overflow-y: auto;
```

To the #page div then you will get a scroll bar inside of that div if and only if you have content inside of it that overflows the height of the div.

[image]

If you are seeing a scroll bar on the right hand side of the page then you have the div #page height set too tall, try reducing the height on that div until that scroll bar goes away.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply too, only i get the same problem what i told Fahad Hasen that reply on my qeustion. 
I want a scrollbar in the div id #content and not the Page. See my image what i want! :)

Comment: You get the body scroll bar because your div is too tall in the first place.

Add even more content to where it is overflowing inside the #page, and apply a overflow-y:auto to #page div. And resize the page div so that it's height is not too tall to view in your browser window.